# Open Browser on Login

Tags: macos, login, web-browser

How would I configure mac's to open a browser to a certain website on login for all users? I work in a lab we need to distribute a survey.

I'm looking for a possible terminal command to configure this.

Comment: If you want a terminal command, I recommend `crontab`.

Comment: @User9125 Can you add an answer below explaining how `crontab` can be used to open a website for all users on login?

Answer (score 4):

To configure an action like **Open Browser on Login** follow these steps:

1. Go to **System *Preferences->Accounts*** and select your user account in the left column
2. Then Select the ***Login Items tab*** on the right. There you see a list of applications and files that you can direct your Mac to open at login)
3. Just drag your **.webloc file(s)** into the Login Items list

And the next time you log in, Your Mac will open automatically the web location (.webloc) you put in Login Items tab (with your default browser)

[image: Start Items]

Here more detailed explanation about how add .webloc files on login startup:  https://www.macworld.com/article/1156341/open_websites_login_startup.html

Comment: I believe he asked for a terminal command.

Comment: Very cool idea. Would have coded an Apple Script to do this.  Did not know you could add webloc files as login items.

Answer (score 4):

Simple.

`defaults write loginwindow AutoLaunchedApplicationDictionary -array-add '{ "Name" = "Website" ; "Path" = "/path/to/file.webloc"; "Hide" = 0; }'`

This command will do exactly what @jasubal's answers does, except its less user friendly and, as requested, is a terminal command.

**UPDATE:** Here is a single command to apply to all users. **Note**: This is untested but should work. From [here](http://www.macinstruct.com/node/427).

`sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/loginwindow AutoLaunchedApplicationDictionary -array-add '{ "Path" = "/path/to/file.webloc"; "Hide" = "0"; }'`

The above command adds a *Global Login Item*.

To remove all Global Login Items you can use the following command:

`sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/loginwindow AutoLaunchedApplicationDictionary.`

**Important: Restart after using these commands for them to take effect**

Comment: thanks! I'll ttest this out. This will open for all new users signing into the system?

Comment: You would have to repeat on each account.

Comment: Looking for a terminal command to add it to every new user. I'm operating a open lab that deletes profiles and new users come all the time.

Comment: Will edit answer soon.

Comment: I'm guessing there's no way?

Comment: @torincsuf Forgot about this will see what I can do today.

Comment: @torincsuf Done. Test if the updated answer works.

Comment: It didn't work.. but just aquired JAMF and rolled it out to my MACs and was able to deploy a policy to do just this. Much easier! thanks for the help josh!

Comment: @torincsuf Sorry it didn’t work :( can you add your answer about JAMF